# xcode 5 - Is it possible to change a section of a UIview instead of putting another uiview on top of it?

Tags: uiimage

I have a card dealing app that deals all 52 cards to the screen as in a solitaire game.  My question is instead of placing 52 UIImage views on top of the screen, is there a way to change a section of a larger imageview to a card's image.  For instance can an imageview sized at 640 x500 pixels have a 20 x 20 pixel section changed at x=10, y=25 without having to put another imageview at that location? So instead of having 53 imageviews there would only be one.

Comment: Sure, either redraw the image or use a layer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by changing the `drawRect:` method of your view. There you could draw each card at its individual position.

If you then change one card, you can redraw only the section of this card with `[view drawRect:rect]` where rect is the frame of the card you changed.

But I would advise you to use a separate UIView for each card, because then you can easily do touch handling and move it around the screen if needed.

Comment: Note that if you go the `drawRect:` route, you'd typically do that in a subclass of `UIView` and not in a `UIImageView` as stated in the details of the question. **However, I also strongly suggest that you use separate `UIView`s for each card!**

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I used your suggestion and used a separate UIView.  I appreciate the reply.

Comment: After using a separate UIView for each card dealt in the deck (52) the memory usage ended up being 280+mb at the end of the game.  This is because each UIView adds 4.9-5.2mb for each new card added to the screen.  I was hoping to decrease the total memory usage by somehow drawing in a section of a single view.  The app is working using a UIView for each card but I know I must be doing something wrong with so much memory being used. Still learning.